How to update an already Fine-tuned GPT2 model?
I have trained my model using GPT-2 for my dataset. It has been trained and is giving the correct output. Now, I want to train my model on more data while retaining the previously trained model. I do not want to create a new model; I only want to use the previous one with the updated data for training.
I tried doing overwrite=False in the training, but I don't know whether it will work or not.

No, there is no way to do this, because continuing training means that the model will forget the previous data, please search for "catastrophical forgetting". And its not a programming problem.

Since you are using transformers, you can simply load your fine-tuned model from disk using from_pretrained() with a local path, instead of specifying the model name, which loads the base (non-fine-tuned) model from HuggingFace (or local cache). If you have not saved your fine-tuned model to disk yet, do so using save_pretrained(), and use the same path that you specify here in from_pretrained() to load the model and continue training.
This assumes that you are not using things like accelerate, which has its own mechanism for checkpointing, i.e., saving and loading model weights while training.

No, this will not work due to catastrophical forgetting.

@Dr.Snoopy That may not apply here, if the asker is merely interested in continuing training with an expanded dataset (all in-distribution, no transfer/adaption required). Given their wording - "I want to train ... on more data", that seems like the case to me, but they can clarify their intent.

No, incorrect, from the question: "Now I want to train my model on more data while retaining the previous trained model", I read this that they want to keep previous data, which will be catastrophically forgotten.

@P_0  I have already trained my model. Now I have got more data on which I want to train my model. what I want is the "remembers" the previous training and then 'learns' the new data along with it.

@Dr.Snoopy  I have already trained my model. Now I have got more data on which I want to train my model. what I want is the "remembers" the previous training and then 'learns' the new data along with it.

@TANVI Exactly, that is what I am saying its not possible, due to catastrophical forgetting.

@Dr.Snoopy is there any other way or method to do so? Or I have to train the model from the start only

@TANVI Train the model from scratch with all the data.

@Dr.Snoopy okay thank you

So we can never update the model with new data. We have to always restore with updated dataset?
